# How to change endpoints on web service

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am working on calling web service client. Currently, I am connecting to the test environment. In order to connect to production environment I have to connect to production environment. My process in terms of connecting to the test environment is as follows.

1. Copy WSDL to local directory
2. Run `wsdl2java` to generate domain objects and other annotated classes. There is one with `@WebServiceClient` and a couple with `@WebService`
3. From there I am just using the generated objects to call these classes.

What I don't get is where I would change the endpoints for the service call once we go to production environment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe wsdl2Java generate a Proxy class with setEndpointAddress() where you could change the target URL. This method should be located in the generated ServiceLocator.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you check the Service constructor, on the generated code I have, one of the constructors take in a URL as it's arguments.